# How to update multiple columns using array of datas with a prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, node.js, prepared-statement, node-mysql

I have 2 arrays :

```
columns = ['column1', 'column2'];
data = ['data1', 'data2'];
```

I'd like to update the table using a prepared query:

```
conn.query('UPDATE table SET ?? = ? WHERE id = ?', [columns, data, id], 
function(err, info){
```

Excepted sql query :

```
UPDATE table SET column1 = 'data1', column2 = 'data2' WHERE id = 10
```

But I get something that looks like :

`UPDATE table SET 'column1', 'column2' = 'data1', 'data2' WHERE id = 10`

This feature works well for select or insert but it seems not working for update queries. Any thoughts on how I can get this work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [node-mysql docs](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values), about escaping query values, we have this:

> Arrays are turned into list, e.g. ['a', 'b'] turns into 'a', 'b'

, so it won't work the way you expect.

But, in the docs we also have this:

> Objects are turned into key = 'val' pairs. Nested objects are cast to strings.

with an example:

```
var post  = {id: 1, title: 'Hello MySQL'};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
  // Neat!
});
console.log(query.sql); // INSERT INTO posts SET `id` = 1, `title` = 'Hello MySQL'
```

So, in order to do what you want, the best option IMO, is to convert your arrays into an object like:

```
{
  column1: 'data1',
  column2: 'data2'
}
```

Comment: And for those who don't know how to convert arrays into objects:


`var somearray = [ 'data1','data2','data3','etc'];
newObject = Object.assign({}, somearray);
console.log(newObject);`

The primary difference between these being that the object has key'd index while the array does not.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, since after Googling for ages I didn't find an exact example to show what I was looking for. Here is the code which hopefully is what Bobby Shark found out, since I don't think 'SET ??' works.

**To UPDATE multiple columns** (but not necessarily all) for one row, without typing up every column in the query, but passing an object of {*column_name1*: 'new_foo', *column_name2*: 'new_bar', *column_name2*: 'new_baz'}

(using body-parser to get object of form data)

```
var blog = req.body.blog; // object as described above
var sql = "UPDATE blog SET ? WHERE id = ?";

connection.query(sql, [blog, req.params.id], function(err, updatedBlog){
if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect("/blogs/" + req.params.id);
    }
  });
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19358694/10548890) by Bala Clark helped (though we've read it in the docs 10 times!). Hope this helps to see example code of object with multiple column updates (name/value pairs). Again found no specific examples in many sites.