# Update query not work in express js

Tags: express

No any error displayed, but recore still not update.. 
Below my express function for delete.

```
waitingModel.delete = function(id,callback) {
    db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        var sql = 'UPDATE customers_ariving SET deleted = 1 WHERE id='+id;
        console.log(sql);
        connection.query(sql,function(err,data) {
            var result = {};
            if (err) {
                connection.release();
                callback(err, null);
            } else {
                connection.release();
                result = data;
                callback(null, result);
            }
       });
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have find solution from ref link: [Node.js mysql query syntax issues UPDATE WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992879/node-js-mysql-query-syntax-issues-update-where)

> I want to update column deleted=1, so i have added value directly.

```
waitingModel.delete = function(id,callback) {
    db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        var sql = 'UPDATE customers_ariving SET deleted = ? WHERE id = ?';
        connection.query(sql, ['1',id],function(err,data){
            var result = {};
            if (err) {
                connection.release();
                callback(err, null);
            } else {
                connection.release();
                result = data;
                callback(null, result);
            }
        });
    });
};
```